# Qt : Automatic Mouse Click on X,Y position, using QCoreApplication::sendEvent( this, &click); is not Working

Tags: qt

I have Two PushButton on MianWindow, named **CreateEvent** and **Rcreate**, I want to Execute on_CreateEvent_pressed() Event of **CreateEvent** button when i *press* **Rcreate** Button.

I used below Source but its not working.
Thanks

### mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_CreateEvent_clicked()
{
 QMessageBox::information(this,"Mouse Clicked", "This is Mouse Clicked Event");
}


void MainWindow::on_CreateEvent_pressed()
{
 QMessageBox::information(this,"Mouse Pressed", "This is Mouse Pressed Event");
}

void MainWindow::on_Recreate_pressed()
{
 QPoint pos(95,35); /* Button Position to CreateEvent Log  */
 {
  QMouseEvent click(QEvent::MouseButtonPress, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
  click.setAccepted(true);
  QCoreApplication::sendEvent(this, &click); /* Tried with ui->CreateEvent also */
 }
 {
  QMouseEvent click(QEvent::MouseButtonRelease, pos, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::LeftButton, Qt::NoModifier);
  click.setAccepted(true);
  QCoreApplication::sendEvent(this, &click); /* Tried with ui->CreateEvent also */
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call click() slot of an QPushButton object.